# How to resolve 'scanLocation' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Tags: swift, foundation

When trying to use a Scanner I am getting the warning that 'scanLocation' was deprecated in iOS 13.0. Since being able to scan from the next location is rather fundamental to scanning a String, wondering what to use instead of scanLocation. Apple's documentation for [Scanner](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner) does not even mention the deprecation, let alone suggest what has taken the place of scanLocation.

Example of using scanLocation, which is deprecated:

```
while !scanner.isAtEnd {
    print(scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: brackets))
    let block = scanner.string[scanner.currentIndex...]
    print(block)
    scanner.scanLocation = scanner.scanLocation + 1
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

tl;dr - use `currentIndex` instead of `scanLocation` when using `Scanner` in Swift.

Shame on Apple for the poor documentation. But based on information in the NSScanner.h file for the Objective-C version of Scanner, only in Swift, the `scanLocation` property has been deprecated and replaced with the `currentIndex` property.

Answer (score 15):

@rmaddy already gave the correct answer, but this shows how to increment the `currentIndex` since it is different from just adding 1 to the `scanLocation`.

```
while !scanner.isAtEnd {
    print(scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: brackets))
    let block = scanner.string[scanner.currentIndex...]
    print(block)
    scanner.currentIndex = scanner.string.index(after: scanner.currentIndex)
}
```

Comment: how would you reset it back to '0' please? eg. scanner.scanLocation = 0

Comment: You don't. You just create a new instance of `Scanner`

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to do: `scanner.currentIndex = scanner.string.startIndex`?

Comment: Shouldn't this just be `scanner.currentIndex = scanner.string.index(scanner.currentIndex, offsetBy: 1)` (where 1 is the amount to increment by?).

Comment: EDIT: Oh, I see why the loop, to prevent from going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to minimize changes from my existing code:

```
extension Scanner {
    var scanLocation: Int? {
        get {
            for (offset, _) in string.enumerated() {
                let index = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
                if index == currentIndex {
                    return offset
                }
            }

            return nil
        }
        set {
            guard let startValue = scanLocation, let newValue else { return }
            let delta = newValue - startValue
            var offset = 0
            while isAtEnd == false, offset != delta {
                currentIndex = string.index(currentIndex, offsetBy: delta > 0 ? 1 : -1)
                offset += delta > 0 ? 1 : -1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It still represents an API change since `scanLocation` is now optional, but that was a minor adjustment.